# Failed to load joint-controller

Tags: microcontroller, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Cannot load my new controller to gazebo model.
RXCONSOLE shows this message:

```
Node: /gazebo
Time: 189.929000000
Severity: Error
Location: /home/robot/peter_workspace/sandbox/controller/src/robocv_controller_file.cpp:MyControllerClass::init:16
Published Topics: /rosout, /tf, /gazebo/paused, /clock, /gazebo/link_states, /gazebo/model_states, /gazebo/parameter_descriptions, /gazebo/parameter_updates,  /joint_states, /mechanism_statistics

No joint given in namespace: '/velocity_controller')
```

For some reason it refers to location: `Location: /home/robot/peter_workspace/sandbox/controller/src/robocv_controller_file.cpp:MyControllerClass::init:16`

which is the source file for another controller/
ROSPACK shows that both plugins are registered.

What can be wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42537/failed-to-load-joint-controller/) by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 338 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) with karma: 338 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0